# Outstanding balance and amount of interest

Tags: finance

I'm having trouble with this problem:

> A loan is being repaid with level annual payments based on an annual effective interest rate of $8\%$.  If the outstanding balance immediately after the $10$th payment is $1000$, calculate the amount of interest in the $11$th payment

My attempt:

Since $B_{10} = 1000$, then $I_{11} = i*B_{10} = 0.08*1000 = 80$, but I feel like this answer is too easy and I'm missing something

Comment: This sounds like an amortization problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right because $B_t=L\,a_{\overline{n-t}|i}$ and $I_{t+1}=iB_t$.

Comment: OK, but if it's being repaid with **level annual payments**, then the next payment would be $80 as would all future payments, even though the balance is decreasing (unless it's an "in perpetuity" loan). We probably do need the total number of payments to work this out though.

Comment: NO! Each payment $P_t=P$ (constant) at time $t$ is the sum of the principal repayed $C_t$ and interest payed $I_t$. So the next payment won't be 80 (because we have to sum the principal repayment)! and we don't need the total number of payments because at each $t$ we have $I_{t+1}=iB_t$.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your answer. What do you think each payment amount would be, if not 80?

Comment: We cannot calculate each payment because we don't know the number $n$ of payments to find $P=\frac{L}{a_{\overline{n}|i}}$. But doesn' matter because the question is related to the interest payed a time $t+1$ knowing the debt at time $t$ and obviously we pay the interest $iB_t$. So if $I_{t+1}=80$ is the interest a time $t+1$, the payment will be $P_{t+1}\equiv P=C_{t+1}+I_{t+1}=C_{t+1}+80$.

Comment: OK, to me, **level annual payments** means each payment must be the same amount, like in a mortgage or other amortization situation.

Comment: Yes, each payment! not each interest payed! So in the amortization schedule you have a principal repayed part $C_t$ increasing and a interest payed part $I_t$ decrreasing but the sum is constant $P=C_t+I_t$.

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong. I thought amortization would have an effect on annual interest, but it turns out it doesn't. You always pay the same rate of interest on the outstanding balance.